# How to read function attributes from decorator in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

I would like to access function's local variables from the decorator. for example, in the below code I have function called globalfunc that have a variable status and I would like to read status value from the decorator 'deco' before calling the function - is it possible?

```
def deco(func):
    def wrap():
        print(wrap.status)
        func()
        print(wrap.status)
    return wrap

@deco
def globalfunc():
    status="success"


# main
globalfunc()
```

Comment: That's a local variable, not a function attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You have a local variable, not a function attribute. You cannot access a local variable from outside the function.

A function attribute would be assigned like this:

```
def globalfunc():
    globalfunc.status = "success"

globalfunc.status = "notyetcalled"
```

Your decorator would have to take care to transfer the initial value of the `status` attribute to the new `function` object it creates:

```
def deco(func):
    def wrap():
        print(wrap.status)
        func()
        print(wrap.status)

    try:
        current_status = func.status
    except AttributeError:
        current_status = "some default value"
    wrap.status = current_status
    return wrap
```

Now you can write

```
@deco
def globalfunc():
    pass

globalfunc()
```

which outputs

```
"some default value"
"success"
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer from [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) explains you can access function attributes. The [original] question included the term **attribute** but code showed OP was referring to the local variables.

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Not having this feature is better than having one as it could open some security issues with handling data of a different function and scope.

**Possible solutions:**

- Redesign this part of application,
- Use attributes instead (but be careful)

PS. I do not have reputation to add a comment, hence this answer.